# Python Flask Authorization login_user not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login, flask-user

I have a flask app that acts as a login system. I am trying to use `@roles_required()` decorator in order to check if the user is an admin, and if they are, giving them access to specific areas.

When I try log in with the correct credentials, that have been created with the correct roles, it gives me the error below.

`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'get_user_by_token'`

I have located the error, it seems to be that `login_user()` is not working properly. I have commented the line causing an error in `login_post()`.

Let me know if there's anything else you need. **Please help!!! No one can seem to figure it out...**

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user, LoginManager
import json

from flask_user import UserManager, roles_required

USER_ENABLE_EMAIL = False


auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

db.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

from app import auth as auth_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)


app.config['USER_ENABLE_EMAIL'] = False

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    username = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles',
            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# Define the Role data model
class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

# Define the UserRoles data model
class UserRoles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))


user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)




@auth.route('/')
def login():

    return render_template('login.html')


@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

    adminuser = 'adminuser'
    adminpwd = 'adminpwd'

    if username == adminuser:
        if check_password_hash(adminpwd, password):
            login_user(user, remember=remember) # this is the problem
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard')


    if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password): 
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login')) 

    login_user(user, remember=remember) # this is the problem
    return redirect(url_for('auth.profile'))
    


@auth.route('/profile')
@login_required
@roles_required('userClass')
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html')


@auth.route('/admin/dashboard')
@roles_required('Admin')
def admin_dashboard():
    return render_template("admin_dashboard.html")
```

Comment: First, you don't provide the modules you load. Second, assuming you are using `flask-login`, `UserManager` is not in `flask-login` package. Please check again `flask-login` documentation. Did you want to use `Flask-User`?

Comment: I have updated with the modules I am imported @GeorgeEfthymiou

Comment: Do you know what the issue is?? @GeorgeEfthymiou

Comment: First, `@roles_required` is owned by `flask_user` , so it needs the manager of `flask_user`. So you must add the `user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)` Second, for the error `flask_user.ConfigError: Config setting USER_EMAIL_SENDER_EMAIL is missing.` , just add `app.config['USER_ENABLE_EMAIL'] = False` .It removes the requirement for email. P.S.: I'm still on testing.

Comment: By the way, i 'm still trying to figure out if you can use 2 different login modules on the same app.

Comment: Okay it works! However, it redirects to [link](https://ibb.co/TKsCG7t) when I just want it to redirect to `admin.html` as shown in `admin()`. Is this possible? @GeorgeEfthymiou

Comment: Okay, so I log into that page with admin username and password, which gives me `passlib.exc.UnknownHashError: hash could not be identified` @GeorgeEfthymiou

Comment: First, does the user 'admin' exit? Try to register. Second, this page must be by default from `Flask-login` or from `Flask-User`. Try to change the name of `admin.html` to something else.

Comment: I have rewritten the question which has updated code. Please have a look, it includes everything. Feel free to leave an answer so I can upvote if correct. Thanks in advance @GeorgeEfthymiou

Comment: @GeorgeEfthymiou ??

Comment: I think i found the problem. I can't check it now, but you should try it. After `user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)` add `user_manager.login_manager = login_manager` Based on comment from reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/9s363q/flaskuser_user_has_no_attribute_get_user_by_token/eh8yf4b?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3